# How to prevent users from making unauthorized webmethod calls and tampering with clientside validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm creating a web page where users can register themselves and their newly bought product.

So the page initially consists of two input fields: A serial number and their social security number. These values are to be validated against two different API's. The users should not be able to abuse these API-calls since second one costs money for each call. The other one should also be restricted in some way so that users can't get access to all our serial numbers.

And the wish was to make this web page with ajax to create a good user experience. So I'm using the jQuery ajax function to call webmethods that I've put in the codebehind of the page.

In turn, each webmethod calls the matching API using credentials. But doesn't this mean that anyone can edit the script clientside so they can make how many calls they want to the API's?

I need to be able to prevent this. how would I go about doing that? Can I check that the call wasn't initiated by user-inserted script?

Another question, how do I validate on client side that both ajax calls have returned successfully? it's easy if there was only one ajax call. I would just do something in the success: part of the ajax function. I could check that all checkmarks are visible next to the input fields, but that could be easily tampered with by users. SO what is a good way to do this? I want to enable a button once both calls have been made succesfully, so that the user can confirm the results from the API's.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string CheckSerialNumber(String _input)
    {
        string result = null; 
        var client = new CheckSerialNumberClient(); //A service reference to the API
        try
        {
            //make the API call.
            result = client.checkSerialNumber(_input);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = "An error occured";
        }
        return result;
    }

[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomerInfo(String _input)
    {
        string result = null; 
        var client = new CustomerInfoClient(); //A service reference to the API
        try
        {
            //make the API call.
            result = client.getCustomerInfo(_input, myCredentials); //credentials is so that the company that has the API can charge us for each call.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = "An error occured";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

jQuery, I got this to work, but might as well show it. This is after the input has been validated against a regex:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Default.aspx/CheckSerialNumber",
data: ...
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are users logged in when these AJAX calls are made? Check their cookie and restrict which records they can access, or how many records can be accessed in a day, on the server side. That's the only way you can do it reliably, imo; all client-side validation can be subverted.

Comment: no there is no login of any sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make CheckSerialNumber return a nonce (single use key) which will have to be used (and then verified server side) when calling GetCustomerInfo.  This will force your api users to go through CheckSerialNumber before moving on to GetCustomerInfo.

This will solved the problem with calling GetCustomerInfo without going through serial number verification first, but will not prevent someone from calling the first and then the other repeatably until you run out of cash, provided they have at least one verified serial number.

You could limit the number of calls per serial number in which case an attacker will have to generate a list of valid serial numbers (not sure how easy this is)

You can check for the request ip and try to limit calls like that, but honestly it is very difficult to prevent someone determined enough from bypassing such limitations, and so usually such attacks are handled on the network level.  If you're using SSL this would make life a bit more difficult as IP spoofing is not possible when using SSL as far as I know, but again, it's not bullet proof.

Setting cookies etc. is not relevant as deleting cookie or ignoring them is very easy when using attack tools.

As for confirming that all went well, in the success method of the first call, you can call the second verification (if you implement a nonce key you'll have to do it this way anyhow).  Then in the success method of GetCustomerInfo you can confirm that it verified successfully as well.

As a last resort, limit the number of calls you make to the client.getCustomerInfo api in a given time frame, so if someone does bypass your limitations, you can limit the impact the intrusion has by limiting the money you pay for that service.  For example you can say that on average you have 100 calls a minute, so anything above 200 calls per minute should stop the service from serving new requests until you understand if it's a surge of real requests or an attack.

Comment: Nice answer, this helps, but I'm beginning to see that there is no way of completely securing the web page. At least not with my resources.

Comment: There is no "complete security" anywhere, yet web services survive.  The bigger you are, the more resources you can afford to put on security, and usually the more "fire" you attract from hackers.  So don't know how big your company is, but but if you're big enough, you need to provide a complete solution by involving other departments in your company.  If it's only you, just do what you can to give the best protection and limit the impact of possible attacks.  In the end, it's a management decision if the risk it too high to justify the benefit.

Comment: I think the solutions that you suggested will be enough for the company I work for. So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should always verify data sent from clients, no matter if it was validated on the client or not. Otherwise you will be vulnerable to malicious clients. If you are concerned about malicious clients, you must accept that there will be no fool proof way to prevent tampering. You can just make it a little bit harder for them, by using an authentication and authorization system, adding tokens to each request, limiting number of requests allowed and so on ... but even then, there's no absolute security.

If you want to check for both calls being successful, just set some global flags, when your call returns successfully. Or you can initiate the second call not before the first one succeeded. You can also return some token, which is required by later calls, but this can be misused as well.

You might also want to look at the [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) web site for security considerations. Especially the "Reference" and "How To" sections might be useful.

And there will always be clients with javascript turned off and then your website won't work as you expect.

Also think about clients, who want to script theses accesses. Or maybe, you want to offer these web methods as an API, then there will be no client with javascript and you must validate the supplied data on the server anyway.

Comment: I get that I have to assume that client validation can be tampered with, but still.. there must be a better way than to check if my checkmark icons are visible.

Comment: @ErikL You must accept, that there is no absolute security. As long as you're connected, there might also be attackers. *Might* not must! Anyway, I modified my answer, maybe you find it a bit helpful.

Comment: How would I set global flags on clientside? I'm kind of new to client-side script

Comment: @ErikL Just define two variables and use them in your javascript fucntions, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4zBD/2/). You can also add properties to `window` or `document`.

Comment: Oh right, since I'm not gonna be doing any postbacks the variables wont lose their values. Duh :) Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing one ajax call for each web input? Why not combine them into 1, for the form?

Remember, you should always have server side validation in addition to any client side validation. Client side validation is not enough to ensure security. In this case you could use a session variable or a database table to record the number of calls a user has made, against their serial number, which identifies them. Then you would have a way to ignore them after x unsuccessful attempts.

You could also use their IP to identify them, but this is not as robust - many people have dynamic IP addresses which can easily be changed. IP address can also be spoofed  trivially.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could combine the two calls. Your solution would do a lot of good, but I don't think I have the time to create something like that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the Ip address of the user store in a db and only allow x amount of attempts per minute and x amount per day.